# Using streams to print max amount of decimal places after dot

Tags: c++, stream

How can I use stringstream to print the *max* amount of decimal places after the dot of a double number (no trailing zeros and no rounding)? For example, if I only want to print up to 5 decimal places:

```
1 -> 1
1.23 -> 1.23
1.234 -> 1.234
1.2345 -> 1.2345
1.23456 -> 1.23456
1.234567 -> 1.23456
1.2345678 -> 1.23456
1230.2345678 -> 1230.23456 <- Demonstrating that I am not talking about significant digits of the whole number either
```

etc.

Of all of the tools I see (setw, setprecision, fixed, etc.), I can't seem to figure this one out. Thanks!

Comment: There generally is no such thing. For example, when converted to binary floating point, `1.1` will end up as a repeating number. *Most* of the numbers you've given above can only be approximated as floating point numbers, and it's essentially impossible for code to guess whether the 1.22999999997 that's stored is really what you want, or it started out as 1.23 instead.

Comment: What about very big or very small numbers? Like `1.0003e-15 == 10.003e-14`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you absolutely want to do this with `stringstream` options?

You could code a `round` function like this:

```
double round(double n, int digits) {
    double mult = pow(10, digits);
    return floor(n*mult)/mult;
}
```

and then just print `round(1.2345678, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way to do this (as far as I know).  However, a hack like the following would be possible:

```
void print_with_places(double num, unsigned places) {
   for (double i = 1; i < num; i*=10) { //have to use a double here because of precision...
      ++places;
   }
   std::cout << std::setprecision(places) << num;
}
```

It isn't the pretitest, but it's that or print it to a string and then manipulate the string.