`1.0+1e-100=1.` in MIT-scheme
I am reading SICP and read this recitation about chapter 1. I use MIT/GNU Scheme as MIT course 6.5151 (6.905) does with version 12.1.
I am stuck at Problem 3.

Write a procedure that computes e.

I tried to use . So I have code
(define (e x)
  (newline)
  (display (/ 1.0 x))
  (newline)
  (display (+ 1.0 (/ 1.0 x)))
  (newline)
  (display x)
  (expt (+ 1.0 (/ 1.0 x)) x))
(e (expt 10 100))

It has answer 1.. Here I use display to check where the resolution is not as expected. It turns out (display (+ 1.0 (/ 1.0 x))) outputs 1. which is unexpected.
The instructor solution uses Taylor series which is different from the above idea.

What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic

Thanks. https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_5.html scheme probably uses IEEE floating representation. Then my method may have problems with the limited resolution in computer although in maths it works.

If you use exact numbers instead of flonums,  (+ 1 (/ 1 x)) gives 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001/10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. I don't suggest raising that to the x'th power in MIT Scheme unless you have some time and memory to kill, though.

@Shawn Thanks for your solution. This means my solution is not practical.

If you want to stick to the pure Scheme code, you can roll your own adaptive precision arithmetic using streams of decimal digits as the representation.

@WillNess Thanks for your alternative solution. 1.1 Googling "streams of decimal digits" recommends one post about c++ https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186757/21294350 saying we need to multiply 10^k and then floor -> divide by 10^k for precision k. But "multiply 10^k" may cause overflow. I think it is wrong. 1.2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34095030/21294350 uses std::setprecision.


For scheme, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5208049/21294350 may work. I didn't dig into it because learning SICP is not to learn Scheme. The link has many syntaxes absent from SICP up to chapter 1, so I will follow the instructor solution by using Taylor Series.


The initial simplest form of this idea is to represent a number 123 as a datum {3, [1,2,3]} meaning 0.123 * 10^3. Then enhance it as needed.

You also can roll your own fixed precision bigfloat arithmetic by representing numbers as ratios of integers, using 10^n as the same denominator throughout, always, rounding the results after each operation. For example, for n=1, {23%10} ÷ {20%10} = {12%10}. Since your values need at least 100 decimal digits but will undergo many arithmetic operations, you will need n greater than 100. You could try several and see how the end result changes, just like we see in the answer. You'd have to implement exponentiation of these ratios yourself, by repeated squaring, say, rounding after each squaring.

If we use eg 200 digits in the interim numbers, squaring gives us 400 digits. So without rounding these numbers will quickly become enormous in size. This rounding is what makes it fixed precision arithmetic. Each squaring is simply done with the underlying unlimited integers, used for the numerators.

(123%100)^2 = 15129/10000 = {151%100}.

@WillNess Thanks for your patience. In a summary, 1. "{23%10} ÷ {20%10} = {12%10}" is solved by "23/20.0" -> 1.15 and then round to 1.2 -> "12%10". Is the calculation process as you expect?


you means we should use https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186757/21294350 method. "You'd have to implement exponentiation of these ratios yourself, by repeated squaring, say, rounding after each squaring." and "Each squaring is simply done with the underlying unlimited integers": Here 1e-100 must need precision at least 100 decimal bits. Then at last we will encounter Shawn's format where the big exponentiation needs too much time which is impractical.


Then how do we solve the problem using "streams of decimal digits" (could you give the process for the above example)? (Hope my understanding of what you says is right.)


Yes, rounding. 2. No, we divide and round after each multiplication, squaring, etc. We thus always preserve only n decimal digits after each simple operation.  3. No, this is a different representation. We have e.g (a%b) * (c%b)= ( round( (a*c)/b ) % b ) where a, c, b are just Scheme. integers - of course round by using only integer operations, never using floats. I'll see if I can find a related answer if mine.


I failed to move this discussion to chat. As https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388670/why-does-it-always-say-moving-discussion-to-chat-failed#comment722895_388670 says it seems only dev can solve the problem. @WillNess I can understand your point 2. For 3, I think you may mean *10^{b} instead of quotient using %b. "I'll see if I can find a related answer if mine.": "the big exponentiation needs too much time" is where I doubts about the feasibility of this method. Can keeping "squaring" up to 1e100 can be solved in one practical short time using "streams of decimal digits"?

creating chat didn't work for me either. here's what I had in mind.

a^(10^100) = a^(10 * 10^99) = (a^10)^(10^99), so we only need to do 100 steps of to10thPower(x, N) = { x2 := roundPrec( x*x, N) , x4 := roundPrec( x2*x2, N) , x8 := roundPrec( x4*x4, N) , return( roundPrec( x8*x2, N) ) }. for 100 digits let's say we try working with 400 digits of internal results, so the biggest numbers will have around 1600 digits, immediately cut down back to 400, on each step. then we can try N=300, 500 and see whether the result changes, and after which digit - taking it to mean that all the preceding digits are good. Maybe. Something like that.

"streams of decimal digits" is a completely different idea, of somehow representing numbers as objects which can give us first N correct decimal digits of the number's decimal representation; or N+1 digits, etc, on demand. like repr( num_pi, 7) = {1, 3141592} ("1" meaning, it's 0.3141592 * 10^1). thus when we define num_c = num_mult( num_a, num_b) and later ask num_c for its first 100 digits, say, it asks its constituent nums for their digits and it all works out somehow. Just a vague idea.

@WillNess Thanks for your link. I understand now. But "underlying unlimited integers" seems to not hold in Scheme (the reason is probably due to the bit limit same as the floating number). I will post the scheme code translated from your pseudocode in one answer since the code is a bit long.

The problem is that 1 + 10-100 differs from 1 in the 100th decimal place.  That means that, as a float, in order for it to be distinct from 1 you need at least 100 decimal places, or at least about 332 bits of precision.  IEEE 754 double-precision floats have a precision of 53 bits, so there is no way that this can work using double floats.
In general if you're adding numbers of hugely differing magnitudes like this you are going to run into trouble with floating-point, or indeed with any kind of machine integer: if you tried to represent these things as 64-bit integers you still can't do anything useful here.
Using Racket's 'bigfloat' package you can control the precision of floats and see the answer appear.
(require math/bigfloat)

(define (bfe x (precision (bf-precision)))
  (define bfx (bf x))
  (parameterize ([bf-precision precision])
    (bfexpt (bf+ 1.bf (bf/ 1.bf bfx)) bfx)))

Now:
> (bf-precision)
128
> (bfe (expt 10 100))
(bf 1)
> (bfe (expt 10 100) 332)
(bf 1)
> (bfe (expt 10 100) 333)
(bf #e3.13612321207875129576038816881464108475667088571290143008146478665151883781810987619137532041768112489)
> (bfe (expt 10 100) 400)
(bf #e2.7182818284590452353645832758305382066800249084717283867982178383777754898191243109391113320627898418259308185781451392861)

So you can see that to get anything other than 1 you need 333 bits of precision and to get any reasonable answer you need many more bits than that.

Thanks for your more detailed explanation using the more powerful Racket. I use MIT-Scheme same as the course. Someone also recommends using Clojure but I thought the most simple Scheme may teach more with the above introduction book. Here I add some notes about the above syntax for someone only using Scheme as me: 1. precision is one optional argument https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html#%28part..Declaring.Optional_.Arguments%29. 2. parameterize https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/parameterize.html and bf https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/bigfloat.html.

Here is one specific solution for this problem based on stream. Here "specific" means it only considers addition of 2 not very large mixed fractions since at least in MIT/GNU Scheme 12.1 too large integer may be not  differentiated from each other like 1e100 and 1e100+1.
This is based on exercise 3.58 and I wrote this code exactly after finishing that exercise.
Possible improvements:

stream-* doesn't choose prec based on whether a,b are finite fraction with one fixed prec for multiplier and  multiplicand to calculate the appropriate ulp of the result.
->stream can be more general.

Notice:

add-streams-with-carry is based on carry save adder.
See the comments of stream-* for how to choose prec and n.

;;; book-stream-lib.scm

;; modified based on the book one.
(define (add-streams . addends)
  (apply stream-map + addends))

(define (scale-stream stream factor)
  (stream-map (lambda (x) (* x factor)) stream))

;;; ../lib.scm
(define (displayln x)
  (newline)
  (display x))

;;; main.scm
(define decimal-idx 10)
;; up to prec-1 after the decimal point
(define prec 100)

(define (exact-quotient a b)
  (inexact->exact (quotient a b)))
(define (exact-remainder a b)
  (inexact->exact (remainder a b)))

(define (expand num den radix)
  (cons-stream
    (exact-quotient (* num radix) den)
    (expand (exact-remainder (* num radix) den) den radix)))

(define (stream-/ num den radix)
  (cons-stream
    (exact-quotient num den)
    (expand (exact-remainder num den) den radix)))

;; 1. For simplicity, here very large number will not be considered since we only want to calculate 1+1/n, n->\infty.
;; 2. As one demo, here we won't implement Fast Carry using Propagator.
(define zeroes (cons-stream 0 zeroes))
;; 1. based on carry save https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-save_adder#Technical_details (see point 3)
;; similar to the propagate between 2 "carry save adders" https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/727175/341985.
;; 2. stream-head is fine since we are using "every" which must check all elements.
(define (carry-propagate mixed-fraction prec idx)
  (let ((integer-sum (cons-stream (stream-car mixed-fraction) zeroes))
        (decimal-fractions (stream-cdr mixed-fraction)))
    (let ((carry (stream-map (lambda (val) (exact-quotient val idx)) decimal-fractions))
          (sum (cons-stream 0 (stream-map (lambda (val) (exact-remainder val idx)) decimal-fractions)))
          )
      (let ((res (add-streams integer-sum carry sum)))
        (if (every (lambda (val) (< val idx)) (cdr (stream-head res prec)))
          res
          (carry-propagate res prec idx))))))
;; 1. each addend is (cons-stream integer proper-fraction) maybe got from stream-/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction#Mixed_numbers
;; 2. prec means the digit pos of the minimal ulp among all addends where digit pos means cnt at the right of the decimal point starting from 1.
(define (add-streams-with-carry idx prec . addends)
  (let ((intermediate-res (apply stream-map + addends)))
    (carry-propagate intermediate-res prec idx)))
(define (->stream obj)
  (cond 
    ((stream-pair? obj) obj)
    ((number? obj) (cons-stream obj zeroes))
    (else (error "wrong type" obj))
    ))
(define (stream-+ a b)
  (let ((a (->stream a))
        (b (->stream b))
        )
    (add-streams-with-carry decimal-idx prec a b)
    )
  )

;; modified based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30561923/21294350. Also see related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942574/create-an-infinite-stream-from-a-list
;; still return one stream.
(define (append-streams . streams)
  (let* ((valid-streams (remove stream-null? streams))
         (cur-stream (car valid-streams))
         (rest-streams (cdr valid-streams)))
    (if (= 1 (length valid-streams))
      cur-stream
      (cons-stream (stream-car cur-stream)
        (apply append-streams (cons (stream-cdr cur-stream) rest-streams))))))

(define (number-cnt num cnt)
  ;; similar to append-streams
  (define (iter n)
    (if (= 0 n)
      the-empty-stream
      (cons-stream num (iter (- n 1)))))
  (iter cnt)
  )

(define (scale-frac-stream stream scalar prefix-zero-cnt suffix-zero-cnt)
  (assert (stream-pair? stream))
  (let ((non-zero-digits (scale-stream stream scalar)))
    (append-streams (number-cnt 0 prefix-zero-cnt) non-zero-digits (number-cnt 0 suffix-zero-cnt)))
  )

;; prec same as the above definition.
(define (prec->mul-ulp prec)
  (- (* 2 prec) 1))
;; For `(stream-* A B prec)`:
;; A and B may have very large ulp-digit-pos.
;; Then due to `(stream-ref b idx)`, we may have the drop like 1.00...01->1 which actually drops adding A*.00...01.
;; This can have big effects after many exp operations.
;; Actually to have no loss, (prec->mul-ulp prec)>=1+ulp-digit-pos-A+ulp-digit-pos-B where ulp-digit-pos-B contributes prefix zeroes of x * A where x is the rightmost digit of B.
;; So 
;; 1. use one very large prec compared with the possible ulp-digit-pos of A,B during the exp process.
;; 2. Make A,B have no 0 digits always.
;; point 2 is reasonable.
(define (stream-* a b prec)
  (let ((a (->stream a))
        (b (->stream b))
        (digit-cnt-after-decimal-point (- prec 1))
        (ulp (prec->mul-ulp prec))
        )
    (let ((addends 
            (map 
              (lambda (idx) 
                (scale-frac-stream a (stream-ref b idx) idx (- digit-cnt-after-decimal-point idx))
                )
              (iota prec))))
      (apply add-streams-with-carry decimal-idx ulp addends))
    ))
;; http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-1.16
(define (iter-fast-expt-stream b n prec) 
  (define (stream-square a)
    (stream-* a a prec))
  (define (iter N B A) 
    (cond ((= 0 N) A) 
          ((even? N) (iter (/ N 2) (stream-square B) A)) 
          (else (iter (- N 1) B (stream-* B A prec))))) 
  (iter n b (cons-stream 1 zeroes)))

;; see comment of stream-* for why to use random here. But actually not big difference for whether random maybe due to A,B ulp will be smaller much quickly...
(define range 1e50)
(define (test-n n)
  (define res (iter-fast-expt-stream (stream-+ 1 (stream-/ 1 n 10)) n prec))
  ;; first transform to str since that has no precision restriction.
  (let ((res-str
          (fold-right 
            (lambda (idx fold-res) 
              (let ((num-str (number->string (stream-ref res idx))))
                (string-append
                  (if (= idx 0)
                    (string-append num-str ".")
                    num-str)
                  fold-res
                  )))
            ""
            (iota (prec->mul-ulp prec)))))
    (displayln res-str)
    (string->number res-str)))

(define exact-30-digit-e 2.718281828459045235360287471352)

(define n (round (random range)))
(define res1 (test-n n))
; 2.718281828459045442758934615002006527126240527982458701098393907032273107905652826337000531516697130792087466273220790017741994288184439199673939792332212143904701689873406611016744157146734142700200
;; correct up to 2.718281828459045.
(define n range)
(define res2 (test-n n))
; 2.718281828459045442758934615002006527126240527982478429890253640900175140704741819620318549177823255409548230084118712275829443036711865187384775705871084526522810837887447798081277039531818193655490
(abs (- res1 exact-30-digit-e))
; 4.440892098500626e-16
(abs (- res2 exact-30-digit-e))
; 4.440892098500626e-16
(< (abs (- res1 exact-30-digit-e)) (abs (- res2 exact-30-digit-e)))
; #f


@WillNess I add one implementation based on stream hinted by you. You can review this if you have time and are willing to review the above codes (Although a bit not elegant, it at least works).
